# Call SAP web service from iPad/JQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services

I want to call SAP web service in my iPad app, I have access to the SAP ES workplace.
Can anybody please tell me how I should start?

I have html5 pages, I am required to use JQuery.

Any help is highly appreciated. Even if you provide any help links, it will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP webservices use SOAP. Check for possibilities using JQuery with SOAP - afais there isn't much up-to-date information on that.

http://plugins.jquery.com/node/8241